# JavaFX: Bind a list to a member property of elements of another list

Tags: java, properties, javafx, java-8

I have a `ObservableList<SomeDataClass> dataEntries` and a `ObservableList<StringProperty> dataNames`.

I would like to create a binding that ensures that `dataNames` contains `element.nameProperty()` for each `element` in `dataNames`.

Is there something like the following code snippet in the FX libraries?

```
ObservableList<SomeDataClass> dataEntries = ...;
ObservableList<StringProperty> dataNames = ...;

dataNames.bind(dataEntries.memberList(SomeDataClass::nameProperty));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) framework. Then you can just do

```
ObservableList<SomeDataClass> dataEntries = ... ;
ObservableList<StringProperty> dataNames = 
    EasyBind.map(dataEntries, SomeDataClass::nameProperty);
```

Comment: I almost thought that EasyBind would be the right choice. Thanks!